Не работает scheduler aiogram на сервере
Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой при написании бота в телеграмм, который отправляет сообщение пользователю в определенное время. Локально все работает - отвечает на сообщение /start и присылает сообщение в точно указанное время, но если бот работает на сервере, то перестает отправлять сообщения по расписанию и просто отвечает на сообщение /start.
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router, types
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from aiogram.client.bot import DefaultBotProperties


from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, Dict
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import TelegramObject
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


TOKEN = "токен бота"

dp = Dispatcher()


async def send_message_scheduler(bot: Bot, message: str, user_id: int):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=int(user_id), text=message)


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {hbold(message.from_user.full_name)}!")



async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    timezone="Europe/Moscow"

    scheduler.add_job(send_message_scheduler, trigger="cron", hour=12,minute=30,start_date=datetime.now(), kwargs={
                    "bot": bot,
                    "message": 'сообщение по расписанию',
                    "user_id": 'кому отправляется сообщение', 
                },)
    scheduler.start()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


